# How should I care for the rhizome of a small canna seedling?

Tags: plant-health, roots, canna

I had been hybridizing cannas in the summer and have a promising young plant. Should I store its rhizome in a basket in the basement like the big rhizomes or do mini plants need special care? The rhizome is a little lump 2" in diameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moist sawdust in a dark place. In frost free areas you can pot it up or bung it into a planting spot directly in the ground.